# Train Chepe Chihuahua Regional in December

Tags: trains, tickets, mexico

Does anybody has experience taking the Chepe's Train in Chihuahua, Mx? The cheap one (regional) on December? People says that you have you buy the tickets 10 days in advance, other people says that 4 months before?

I'm planning to be there on days when the Express Train won't fit for me, I'll be there from December 18 to 22th. I'm afraid to be there and be unable to get tickets :(.

Thanks

///
En Español:

Quiero hacer el viaje del tren el Chepe del 18 al 22 de Diciembre.

Pero el 18 es Miércoles, y no hay salidas del tren express ni del regional.

Los horarios publicados son:

CHEPE REGIONAL

Lunes – Jueves – Sábado de Chihuahua, Chih. a Los Mochis, Sin.

Martes – Viernes – Domingo de Los Mochis, Sin. a Chihuahua, Chih.

CHEPE EXPRESS

Martes – Viernes – Domingo de Creel, Chih. a Los Mochis, Sin.

Lunes – Jueves – Sábado de Los Mochis, Sin. a Creel, Chih.

Si llego a Chihuahua el día Miércoles 18, qué tan probable es que ya no haya salidas en el regional del día Jueves 19?

Si me bajo en El fuerte el jueves 19, y quiero regresar a Creel el día Viernes 20, será difícil que consiga lugar en el tren regional?

En algunos lugares dicen que el tren regional se puede comprar 10 días antes, otros dicen que debe ser 4 meses antes, ustedes tienen alguna experiencia?

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: I have no personal information about this. This webpage https://www.cantravelwilltravel.com/book-el-chepe-train-tickets-copper-canyon-mexico/ from February 2019 recounts one traveler's experience in (finally) obtaining El Chepe tickets in advance.